# Index out of bounds error returned from form Recognizer API server on train request

Tags: python-3.x, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

When I try to train a model with 5 pdf's, I get a 200 response from the API server, and all documents have no errors and a status of success, but the error filed of the response itself returns: {'errorMessage': 'Unable to extract key/value pairs. list index out of range'}.  It appears there might be a bug on the API server.

I've successfully trained a model and analyzed the pdf's provided as sample invoices.  And, the training API request for my data returns a 200 result.  So, it really seems like something wrong on server side.  Possible caused by something in the data I'm sending?  But, I'm not able to access a trace for the error, obviously.

```
########### Python Form Recognizer Train #############
from requests import post as http_post

# Endpoint URL
base_url = r"https://westus2.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/" + "/formrecognizer/v1.0-preview/custom"
source = r"https://formrecognizerblob1.blob.core.windows.net/$root/...
headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': <key>,
}
url = base_url + "/train" 
body = {"source": source}
try:
    resp = http_post(url = url, json = body, headers = headers)
    print("Response status code: %d" % resp.status_code)
    print("Response body: %s" % resp.json())
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

Executing the above code (with my 5 pdf's in the root container of my blob storage) returns:

Response status code: 200
Response body: {'modelId': 'e6dd8978-dfcc-438b-b0b2-639c13327cdf', 'trainingDocuments': [{'documentName': '.pdf', 'pages': 5, 'errors': [], 'status': 'success'}, {'documentName': '.pdf', 'pages': 4, 'errors': [], 'status': 'success'}, {'documentName': '.pdf', 'pages': 17, 'errors': [], 'status': 'success'}, {'documentName': '.pdf', 'pages': 7, 'errors': [], 'status': 'success'}, {'documentName': '.pdf', 'pages': 11, 'errors': [], 'status': 'success'}], 'errors': [{'errorMessage': 'Unable to extract key/value pairs. list index out of range'}]}

Answer (score 0):

It does indeed look like a backend bug. If you can share the data you used for training, I could do some further investigation.